# http://localhost:7101/console/login/LoginForm.jsp default username and password?

Tags: oracle, authentication, default, jdeveloper

I just downloaded Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7.1, I'm very new to this, I integrated web logic service, (WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.5.0)
however, I don't know what is the default username and password to log in!

Comment: Try weblogic/weblogic1. Have you tried googling the question before asking here?

Comment: Yes, I have.
I tryed  weblogic/weblogic1 , wlecome , oracle , oracle1 ... 
none works

Comment: You can reset the password. http://www.java-n-me.com/2013/03/jdeveloper-11gr2-and-wls-password-reset.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try weblogic/welcome1. It worked for me. Use 'welcome1' instead of 'weblogic1' as the password.